eBPF XDP - Bad map relocation
I have a short program with two eBPF maps, one used to redirect to an AF_XDP socket, and another to keep track on statistics.
However, when trying to load this program, the following error appears:
libbpf: prog 'xdp_sock_prog': bad map relo against 'xsks_map' in section '.maps'
But, when I comment out the second map (xdp_stats_map), the program loads as usual.
Until a few days ago, this program was able to be loaded normally. But, only after updating the Kernel from 5.12 to 6.5.0 this error started to occur. Would this be related to my problem?
struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_XSKMAP);
    __type(key, __u32);
    __type(value, __u32);
    __uint(max_entries, 64);
} xsks_map SEC(".maps");

struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERCPU_ARRAY);
    __type(key, __u32);
    __type(value, __u32);
    __uint(max_entries, 64);
} xdp_stats_map SEC(".maps");

SEC("xdp")
int xdp_sock_prog(struct xdp_md *ctx)
{
    int index = ctx->rx_queue_index;
    __u32 *pkt_count;

    pkt_count = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&xdp_stats_map, &index);

    //int cpu = bpf_get_smp_processor_id();
    if (bpf_map_lookup_elem(&xsks_map, &index)) {
        //bpf_printk("TEST %d %d", cpu, index);
        return bpf_redirect_map(&xsks_map, index, 0);
    }

    return XDP_PASS;
}

Thanks in advance
In some other XDP programs I have, if it has only one map declared, it loads, but after adding another copy of the map with a different id, this error happens too.

The error comes from the libbpf loader, not from the kernel. How did you install libbpf? Could you share a full reproducible example, including the steps you used to load the program?

Thanks for the help! I followed the setup dependencies tutorial from xdp-tutorial. Also, the program I'm trying to load is advanced03, which has a loader which, roughly speaking, setup the environment required to handle AF_XDP (allocate memory for UMEM etc), loads the program, and adds an entry for the XSK map.

It seems that the problem was solved and it was indeed related to libbpf. It seems that xdp-tools wasn't compiling properly due to problems related to the version of clang and llc used, as this link shows. But thank you very much for pointing that out!

Glad to know you sorted it out! If you think you have a good grasp of what was going on, I encourage you to post an answer to your question. That may help others.

It looks like xdp-tools wasn't compiling correctly due to an older version of clang and llc. So, I updated to clang-16 and llc-16 following this link link, and it worked
